# How to connect to desktop dock by code

Tags: android, bluetooth, dock

How could I connect to the desktop dock by code if the phone is already paired (not connected) to the dock?

Comment: Are you wanting to use an intent to launch the dock application?  Or are you looking to get some information or do something with the dock activity?

Comment: I want to connect the phone to the dock and start the dock application without putting the phone in the dock.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to send a broadcast event of `android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT` and send extras `Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE` as either `Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_CAR` or the desk equivalent. If you do this, then you will mess up the state of your phone, so make sure to send `Intent.EXTRA_DOCK_STATE_UNDOCKED` when your app terminates...

**UPDATE**
Accodring to UiModemanager: start the intent `ACTION_MAIN`  with category `CATEGORY_DESK_DOCK`  to display the desk UI. That is probably the way to do it.

Comment: I've tried to broadcast a DOCK_EVENT but it seems as if I'm not allowed to broadcast it. Sending it throws a SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.DOCK_EVENT from pid=9517, uid=10134. It doesn't seem as if there's a permission which allows an application to broadcast such an intent.

Comment: I wonder if http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/UiModeManager.html is useful at all

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying simulate docking the phone just use a magnet on the back of the phone. You just got to make sure that the polarity is correct. One way will bring up the car dock. If this happens just flip the magnet around to get the desk dock.

Comment: Are you serious? The dock can be triggered with a magnet?

Comment: Yes. thats all the docks are is magnets using surrtan polarities. I don't know what phone you are using. But for a Droid the magnet inside the phone is placed between the Motorola M sign and the indentation of the battery cover that is right of the camera and opposite of the golden speaker grill. If you are using a different phone you can probably Google where the docking magnet is on your phone.

Comment: I think the nexus one might have a magnet. I am not sure the forums aren't being discribtive

Comment: you could try dragging a magnet across the back slowly. the magnet should catch a tiny bit.

Comment: This would only work on the Motorola Droid/Milestone which has a hall effect sensor that detects the dock state and type. The Nexus One does not have this AFAIK. I think it uses the pins at the bottom for the dock.